# How to use a proxy list with socket in python to ping a ip?

Tags: python, sockets, ip, ping

I am using python and socket, I want to use a proxy list, but I am not estbalishing a http connection(Or am I??), but I am using it to ping a ip, I would like to know how to use proxies to ping a ip with another ip?

````py
def ping(ip):
        port = 80
        udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
        data = random._urandom(65500)
        udp.sendto(data, (ip, port))
        wait = input()```
````

Answer (score 0):

don't put random ports
 
each proxy has his own port that you should use
 
at least that what worked for me